# Concatenating each element of a list with a string

Tags: r

A bunch of character objects are defined. They are then described in a list using `ls`. I would like to concatenate each of these objects with a separate string.

```
String = "stringToCombine"
Folder1 = "NameOne"
Folder2 = "NameTwo"
Folder3 = "NameThree"

ls(pattern="Folder")
[1] "Folder1" "Folder2" "Folder3"

Folder1
[1] "NameOne"
```

I'm able to concatenate the string with the object names, but not values, using `assign`. I think `get` might be the way to do this, but I'm unsure of how to apply it.

```
for (i in ls(pattern="Folder")) {
    assign(i, paste(String, i, sep="/"))
    }
```

Desired output:

```
Folder1
[1] "stringToCombine/NameOne"
```

Actual output with the above code:

```
Folder1
[1] "StringToCombine/Folder1"
```

I suspect it's a simple fix, but would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `get`

```
for (i in ls(pattern="Folder")) {
    assign(i, paste(String, get(i), sep="/"))
}
Folder1
[1] "stringToCombine/NameOne"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest storing these in a named vector like this:

```
 myFolders <- sapply(mget(ls(pattern="Folder")),
                     function(x) paste(String, x, sep="/"))
```

This returns

```
myFolders
                    Folder1                     Folder2                     Folder3 
  "stringToCombine/NameOne"   "stringToCombine/NameTwo" "stringToCombine/NameThree"
```

With the named vector, you can refer to each element by its name like this:

```
myFolders["Folder1"]
                  Folder1 
"stringToCombine/NameOne"
```

as well as by its position in the vector: `myFolders[1]`. You can also then loop through the vector to access files with a `for` loop or an `lapply`/`sapply`.

---

As `paste` will directly accept lists as arguments, you can make this even shorter (and more efficient) to produce an unnamed vector like this:

```
paste(String, mget(ls(pattern="Folder")), sep="/")
[1] "stringToCombine/NameOne"   "stringToCombine/NameTwo"   "stringToCombine/NameThree"
```

To apply the names in this construction, wrap it in `setNames`.

```
setNames(paste(String, mget(ls(pattern="Folder")), sep="/"), ls(pattern="Folder"))
```

---

An second alternative is to use the `file.path` function, which is intended to provide operating system-specific legal paths:

```
setNames(file.path(String, mget(ls(pattern="Folder")), sep="/"), ls(pattern="Folder"))
                  Folder1                      Folder2                      Folder3 
"stringToCombine/NameOne/"   "stringToCombine/NameTwo/" "stringToCombine/NameThree/"
```